# How to do a bulk insert using WCF in a Worker Role

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I have a WCF running in a Worker Role with a method that does an insert in Tables.

I have a lot of clients that will access this method to insert data in Tables, but I really need performance on this.

Inside my insert method I do the insert one by one, so I want to change this to do a bulk insert after my WCF receives a 100 records. How can I do that, where I can store a variable with a list of this records to do a bulk insert later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really need to think about the durability (or lack thereof) of your data. If you wait for 100 uploads, where will you store your data temporarily? The only *safe* place is in blobs, tables, or queues (or SQL Database Service).

If you store in RAM, it's volatile and you may lose your data (plus your data will be split across your multiple server instances, so you might actually end up buffering far beyond 100 data items before flushing one of the server instances).

If you store in queues, you'll hit the same performance curve as writing to tables. Same with blobs.

This may be a premature optimization. Table Storage gives you 2,000 transactions per second, per partition (up to 20,000 transactions per second across the storage account). And you can have multiple storage accounts.

Assuming you partition your data carefully (with varying partition keys, vs. storing everything in one partition), you should see well over 2,000 transactions per second for your storage throughput.

You'll also be able to move up to 10Gbps inbound to your storage account. Considering that the *maximum* NIC bandwidth is 2Gbps for our new 8-core 56GB machines, you'd need 5 of those running simultaneously to approach that limit. With single-core VMs (with 100Mbps per core), you'd need, oh, 100 instances to saturate the ingress bandwidth potential of the storage account.

All details about storage account bandwidth are in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2012/11/02/windows-azure-s-flat-network-storage-and-2012-scalability-targets.aspx).

Comment: So how can I gain this 2,000 inserts per second inside a WorkerRole?

Comment: A worker role equates to a Windows Server virtual machine. Just design your WCF service to handle multiple incoming requests simultaneously. Can your WCF service handle 2,000 uploads per second? If so, why wouldn't you be able to write 2,000 times per second to storage? This also begs the question: Have you tried do any benchmarking yet? A bit difficult to optimize if you don't even have a baseline yet.